# Is there one word that describes the attribute of being either disposable or reusable?

Tags: antonyms, hypernyms, category

For example:

Red and blue are to color as disposable and reusable are to __________

Comment: Note that disposability and reusability are not always mutually exclusive. A paper cup is both disposable and reusable.

Comment: Cyclability, but it isn't very common.

Comment: A and B are to C as D and E are D+ 1 [ity]? It does not work. That would give us: "as disposable and reusable are to reusability". As disposable and reusable are to [some object] and not a quality thereof. Unless the question is rewritten. Just as colors can be red or blue, objects can be disposable or reusable. Color does not collate with the notions given by suffixes with ITY in them. Red and blue are types of color; just as disposable and reusable are types of objects.

Comment: @PhilSweet I like where you went with Cyclability. I was thinking Processing. (as in waste processing).

Answer (score 16):

You might consider "reusability", if nothing better is forthcoming.  Low reusability would describe the attribute of "disposable".

[reusability](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reusability) - noun: the state or quality of being reusable

Comment: A and B are to C as D and E are D+ 1? It does not work. That would give us: "as disposable and reusable are to reusability". To me, that makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 14):

Consider "**durability**", which is defined by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/durability) as

> staying strong and in good condition over a long period of time

Indeed, consumer goods that are meant to be reused over a relatively long period of time are called *durable goods* in economic jargon.

Comment: Best answer so far.

Comment: However, "durable medical equipment" (as defined by health insurance companies in the United States, anyway) includes syringes, catheters, and other items that are labeled by the manufacturer as being non-reusable.

Comment: I disagree. Durability seems to be more geared towards robustness or the ability to sustain incremental amounts of damage, and as such is the measurement of its resistance. It's close, but not related to, _reusability_ (which I think is the correct word here).

Comment: A and B are to C as D and E are D+ 1? It does not work. That would give us: "as disposable and reusable are to durability". To me, that makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Lambie There are lots of characteristics where the name of one extreme nearly matches the name of the characteristic itself.   As short and long are to _length_.  As weak and strong are to _strength_.  As transparent and opaque are to _opacity_, or for that matter _transparency_.

Comment: @Doug Warren I don't know what an extreme is. Is that a logic term? Red and blue are to color cannot be compared to "reusable or disposable" + a noun with an ity suffix. That is a misreading. Red and blue are color "types" if you will. Just as usable and disposable are characteristics of object types.

Comment: @Lambie: Red and blue can be adjectives, just as disposable and reusable are adjectives.  Color and durability (or reusability) are both nouns.  Red and blue both describe the color of an object, just as disposable and reusable describe the durability of an object.

Comment: Just as disposable and reusable are adjectives for objects.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't, nor anything like it.

While some disposable items are in fact reusable - eg, batteries or paper cups - that is no more a useful or meaningful fact than that all resuable items are disposable.

That which is classified by its makers and distributors and sellers and buyers and users as disposable is, so far as it could matter, meant not to be re-used.

That which is classified by its makers and distributors and sellers and buyers and users as reusable is, so far as it could matter, meant not to be disposed; not lightly, anyway.

If you really want to find meaning in a comparison like "Red and blue are to color as disposable and reusable are to __________" then why not try "to things"?

Answer (score 1):

How about *usable*?

> Red and blue are to color as disposable and reusable are to *usable*.

Red and blue are both colors. Objects that are disposable and objects that are reusable are both *usable* -- the former once [or perhaps several times, as per Kys's example of a paper (or plastic) cup], the latter an unlimited number of times (for the purpose of answering your question).

M-W:

> [*usable*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/usable): capable
>   of being used
>
> [*disposable*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disposable):
>   designed to be used once and then thrown away
>
> [*reusable*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reusable):
>   capable of being used again or repeatedly

These definitions support *usable* as a solid answer. What disposable and reusable objects have in common is that they are all *usable*. The number of uses is all that varies.

Instead of the adjective *usable*, you could use the noun *usability*, which would parallel the use of the noun *color* in your example.

M-W:

> [*usability*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/usability):
>   capable of being used

Answer (score 0):

Consider [usage](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/usage) [MWD]

> 1. the act of using something
> 2. the way that something is used
> 3. the amount of something that is used

Answer (score -1):

I would think "**waste**" makes sense here.

Waste is the common factor in both disposable and reusable. You generally re-use something that has already been used and would otherwise be discarded (waste). And something that is disposable is again disposed of after use (waste).

Comment: I disagree. As long as something can be reused, it's not waste. Waste can be recycled though. Also, consider adding a reference to back up your claim.

Answer (score -7):

I'd say: red OR blue is to color as disposable OR reusable is to **batteries**.

Objects are not usually disposable AND reusable. They are disposable OR reusable.

Comment: Except that the terms can be used to describe cleaning products (i.e. disposable wipe versus reusable sponge), cameras, diapers, toothbrushes, and many more things.  -1, sorry.

Comment: AND in this context signifies the formation of ordered pairs, not the logical operator.

Comment: @cobaltduck    I never said there were not others. My main point which none of you downvoters understood is that the conjunction is OR and not AND. I repeat: cameras are disposable OR reusuable. Not disposable AND reusable. So are all the other examples you gave. I chose to only give ONE example. No, AND does not work here.

Comment: The answers with all the points state this: A and B are to C as D and E are D+ 1? (the suffix ity being + 1). It does not work. That would give us: "as disposable and reusable are to reusability" (or durability). How can that possibly make logical semantic sense?

Comment: I think that all the other answers take into account the question TITLE as well as the body of the question.  Your answer of "batteries" in no way "describes the attribute of being either disposable or reusable".

Comment: red and blue are not attributes of color. Hue, saturation and brightness are attributes of color. I read the sentence given as an example. Not the title. So, hue, saturation and brightness is to color, as reusable and disposable are to objects.

Comment: "I read the sentence given as an example".  Except you changed it by replacing "and" with "or".  So you ignored the question in the title, changed the body of the question, and then said that everyone else is wrong for answering the ACTUAL question.

Comment: Not at all. You can use AND and you end up with the "ities" being wrong. Red and blue are to color (semantics, not logic) as reusable and disposable are to objects. No ity. And now I have five downvotes. The more the better. So, the question was logically answered and my answer works for AND (semantics) and OR (logic). I know how annoying it can be to have someone like me around. Sorry.

Comment: Yes, you are definitely smarter than everyone else here.  It must be terribly boring for you.  You say that "Red and blue are to color (semantics, not logic) as reusable and disposable are to objects".  I say that "Red and blue are to color (a property of objects) as reusable and disposable are to a property of objects".  Reusability is a property of objects.  I'll stop reading your responses now so that you can have the last word.

Comment: Like me, i.e. picky.

Comment: The OP is looking for a hypernym of (both) *disposable* and *reusable*, so the conjunction is appropriate.

Comment: Make sure to go through everyone of my answers and comment on it and downvote it.  I expect nothing else.